# how to fetch json file in s3 bucket in javascript 3

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

I already have this code in express

```
const express = require('express');
const { S3 } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

const app = express();
const port = 3100;

const s3 = new S3({ region: 'us-west-2' });

app.get('/s3/sample', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const params = {
      Bucket: `bucket`,
      Key: `category/file.json`,
      ContentType: "application/json",
    };

    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        try {
          const json = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString('utf-8'));
          console.log(json);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Error parsing JSON:', err.message);
          console.log('JSON string:', data.Body.toString('utf-8'));
          console.log('data:', data);
        }
      }
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: 'An error occurred while creating the table and inserting rows',
    };
  }
});
```

I keep getting `[object Object]`.
Already tried `ContentType: "application/json",`.
already tried `utf-8`.
Also ask chatgpt nothing is working.

this is the json file

```
[
  {
    "imageThumbUrl": "",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "sku": "xxxx",
    "name": "xxxx",
    "price": 0,
    "allowedTransportModes": "xxxxx",
    "distributionPoints": "xxxxx",
    "availableForDeliveryFrom": "2021-01-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "availableForDeliveryTo": "2024-05-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "categories": ""
  }
]
```

I dont know why i keep getting object object. I tried researching, it looks like im the one experiencing this

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call `data.Body.toString()` on the `Body`, because `Body` is of type `Readable` as described in the [AWS JS SDK Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/getobjectoutput.html#body)

You can use this function to get the full `Body` string from the returned `Readable`:

```
const getReadableData = readable => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    readable.once('error', (err) => reject(err));
    readable.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
    readable.once('end', () => resolve(chunks.join('')));
  });
};
```

So instead of using

```
const json = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString('utf-8'));
console.log(json);
```

use

```
const promise = getReadableData(data.Body);
promise.then(value => {
  const decodedJson = JSON.parse(value);
  console.log(decodedJson);
});
```